# How to change directory details (e.g. Author, Date...) using vba

Tags: windows, vba, mkdir

I'm looking for some solution how to change folder property - "Author". 
I've found "Shell" solution how to get this info:

```
Dim sFile As Variant
Dim oShell: Set oShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
Dim oDir:   Set oDir = oShell.Namespace("c:\foo")

For Each sFile In oDir.Items
   Debug.Print oDir.GetDetailsOf(sFile, 9) 
Next
```

but I need to change this value.
Have you got any experience with it?

Answer (score 0):

You may use ChDir:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg264410.aspx

For more information see help from vba editor

Comment: Thanks, but this will change AUTHOR to my name. What if I want different value e.g "John Doe"?